# Looking for a fantasy love story with time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read a book in the 90's that was a romantic story.

More than 1 book made up the story- I think possibly 2 parts.

It was about a girl who ended up at an old mansion when on a walk.  She went into the old ballroom and she had an "episode".  It was described that the room was spinning and when it stopped she had fallen back into the time of when the house was occupied. The floor was white and black squares...

There was a bit when she mentions that the other girls thought it strange she was wearing jeans and should be wearing a dress (so really old fashioned).

She falls in love with the son and they have a love affair.

She drops back into present day at points, but keeps going back to the mansion and falling again to this boy.

I really want to know what it is called and who wrote it as it was a lovely story and would love to read it again...any idea on what it may be or how i can find out with just this information as it is all i can really remember?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds exactly like *Both Sides of Time* from Caroline B. Cooney's [*The Time Travelers Quartet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Travelers_Quartet).

> Annie Lockwood is watching her boyfriend, Sean, while he fixes his car, and she questions whether or not this is the right relationship for her. Then later, while she looks through the amazing Stratton Mansion she is wrenched from her time (approximately 1995) back 100 years into the past. In this past, she meets the inhabitants of the house, including a young man named Strat. Murders happen in the house, and Annie soon falls in love with Strat, and she ends up going back and forth between the two time periods, But where will she end up? And with whom?